# dataframe.persist can't store temporary result

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I persist a dataframe (32 records), and pass it to another function. But I found there is no data to show, dataframe's show method called in next function. Actually, I've changed its original table, so that dataframe will compute again from the original table. So I want to know why I persist this dataframe, but Physical Plan still compute from table scan instead of persisted dataframe

I want to store the temporary result, even if the original table has changed. How does the persist function works, code just like this.

```
df = spark.sql(select xxx from db.t1) 
df.show() # 32records 
df.persist(DISK_LEVEL) 
func() # change db.t1 
df.show() # empty
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible piece of code to your question?